# MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem sometimes not working

Tags: android, mediastore, contentobserver

I faced a problem I can't handle by myself, I have checked literally every single line of code, but it's still not working.

I have draggable listView, which represents a playlist (ordinary MediaStore.Audio.Playlist) and drop listener for changing order of songs.

```
listView.setDropListener(new DragSortListView.DropListener() {
                @Override
                public void drop(int i, int i2) {
                    if(playlistId != -1) {
                        boolean moved = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem(getContentResolver(), playlistId, i, i2);
                        System.out.println("Item moved " + moved);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Also I have contentObserver, which handles cursor reloading.

```
private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    MyContentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange,  Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        System.out.println("Updated");
    }
}
```

Of course handle is registered

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://media"), true, contentObserver);
```

But here's a problem - moveItem always returns true, but order of songs remains same. On 2.3.6 moveItem doesn't work at all, on 4.4.2 - sometimes, on sony tablet with 4.4.4 - everything works well. I also tried this code with same result

```
public static final boolean moveItem(ContentResolver res,
                                     long playlistId, int from, int to) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external",
            playlistId)
            .buildUpon()
            .appendEncodedPath(String.valueOf(from))
            .appendQueryParameter("move", "true")
            .build();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, to);
    return res.update(uri, values, null, null) != 0;
}
```

Comment: I do have the same problem. Have you found a solution by now?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented drag and drop on my playlist details. Most (if not all came from this forum) Mine looks more complex than your method.
Perhaps the code snippets below will help you
Set a longclicklistener on the row in listview (track on the playlist)

```
private final class MyItemLongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                   int row, long rowid) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
            Cursor crs = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(row);
            int audio_id = crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID));
            int _id = crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID));
            int playorder_col = crs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER);
            String playorder = crs.getString(playorder_col);
            String text = row + ":" + audio_id + ":" + lngplaylist_id + ":" +
                    playorder +
                    ":" + _id;
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(text);
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(text, new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN, ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, item);
            dragData.addItem(new ClipData.Item(String.valueOf(row)));
            mListView.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(dragData, //data to be dragged
                    shadowBuilder, //drag shadow
                    v, //local data about the drag and drop operation
                    0   //no needed flags
            );
            //            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


  class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    public int PositionOfDraggedItem = -1;
    public int PositionOfItemDraggedOver = -1;

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int row = 0;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                PositionOfDraggedItem = mListView.pointToPosition((int) (event.getX()), (int) event.getY());
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                row = mListView.getPositionForView(mListView);
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

   and so on
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have any problems with updating list itself or dragging elements -  actual changing of song position in playlist doesn't happen. And I don't see that part in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void drop(int i, int i2) {
    if(playlistId != -1) {
        boolean moved = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.moveItem(getContentResolver(), playlistId, i, i2);
        System.out.println("Item moved " + moved);

        // scan playlists
        String url = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Playlists";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
    }
}
```